# not able to achieve 100% coverage on equals(object) with lombok @Data annotation

Tags: spring-boot, junit, lombok

i am trying to cover more than 90% , actually trying for 100%.

with all these i am getting 75% to 80%
here am talking about only equals method. am i missing anything ?

found one article on EqualsVerifier but did not understand how to use it in my code.
https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/errormessages/coverage-is-not-100-percent/

```
 @Data
   public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    }
```

my test code

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class PersonTest {

    @Test
    public void testEquals_PositiveScenario() {
        // Create two Person objects with the same attributes
        Person person1 = new Person("John", 30);
        Person person2 = new Person("John", 30);

        // Check if they are equal using the equals() method
        assertTrue(person1.equals(person2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NegativeScenario_DifferentName() {
        // Create two Person objects with different names
        Person person1 = new Person("John", 30);
        Person person2 = new Person("Alice", 30);

        // Check if they are not equal using the equals() method
        assertFalse(person1.equals(person2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NegativeScenario_DifferentAge() {
        // Create two Person objects with different ages
        Person person1 = new Person("John", 30);
        Person person2 = new Person("John", 25);

        // Check if they are not equal using the equals() method
        assertFalse(person1.equals(person2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NegativeScenario_NullObject() {
        // Create a Person object
        Person person = new Person("John", 30);

        // Check if it is not equal to null using the equals() method
        assertFalse(person.equals(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_NegativeScenario_DifferentClass() {
        // Create a Person object
        Person person = new Person("John", 30);

        // Check if it is not equal to an object of a different class using the equals() method
        assertFalse(person.equals(new Object()));
    }
}
```

Comment: probably different permutations of `null` in person's name

Answer (score 1):

When you build your project, you will have an output directory containing your code + generated code added by tools like Lombok. Find your `Person.class` file and take a look at the code lombok added. Then you can update your tests accordingly.

[image: Person.java]

HOWEVER... shooting for 100% code coverage is usually not a good idea. It can create a false sense of security (code coverage doesn't always mean that much), as well as cause you to write a bunch of useless tests.
Remember, **every test adds to the cost of ownership of the application**. Do you really need to be testing the Java language (e.g. getters/setters, generated code, ETC)?

Lombok can add an `@Generated` annotation to code it adds, and most code scanners will not include it in the report (the configuration is `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true`). This way you can test the important parts, and exclude the rest while still achieving high code coverage.

Good luck!